# Assign color value to css variables

Tags: html, css, typescript, vuejs2

In my css i have several color variables like:

```
$bkg-color: #ffffff
```

white is what i want the default color to be but the $bkg-color could also be customized to a different color based on what the user creates and saves.  So in my typescript i have:

```
backgroundColor?: string = '';
```

my get call response data is set to pageDetails and then i check

```
if(pageDetails.backgroundColor) { 
this.backgroundColor = pageDetails.backgroundColor; 
}
```

I cannot directly bind the background color class to the html because my page content is displayed via `v-html='displayedHtml'`

How can i set `$bkg-color: this.backgroundColor` (if exists || set default color of white).

i am using vue and typescript

i believe i can set the default like so: `$bkg-color: #ffffff !default;` but how i can make it assigned based on my data is where i am a bit lost.

Comment: Not fully following, scss variables cannot be changed at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can i set $bkg-color: this.backgroundColor (if exists || set default color of white).
```

Unfortunately, Scss variables do not exist at runtime, they exist only at compile time and then the python-written compiler replaces them with their value in the css style sheet. If you're not supporting Internet Explorer You can use `css variables` to solve this problem which can be changed at run time dynamically.

If iv'e misunderstood the question let me know and i'll add an edit.

EDIT: 
https://jsfiddle.net/njsrLywt/ Here's a demo showing changing css variables at run-time.

EDIT2: You will also no longer be able to use lighten/darken however you can use a javascript implementation of lighten/darken which exists at run-time. Also on a side note you should avoid using lighten/darken in favour of scale-color which allows for better color scaling because it scales the remaining % of 100

EDIT3: Here is a quick implemtation of scale-color implemented with javascript 100% fully immutable FP style use it in the following way

```
ColorUtils.scaleColor("#294e80", -35);  //darken 35%
ColorUtils.scaleColor("#F6F6F6", 35); // lighten 35%
```

https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2J4CcCqAXAliGBvAUAJATphbDQTBggCmCSy0AvNABTCIoAStAHgC5K6ZJgB2AcwA00AA61kwWmPRCxAVwC2AIwUBKFgD5oBQoQD0AKmiZ0AchgALMMgAm0dPGgSvAM2TwmtCO-NAAtMaOECDQYMDA6shktCAAnpRemN5+AUEhfOHGyBLahdBitADu0NwAygAyZfnQluZEhJxiJNAASgDiAEIswfwAKvA9JRxcyLx8egDc7Zi+7P1DzJvl6iAgBsi06Ili0JyMc0tmnd0A2o4yEDIgALrDxdoATFEgbDfrAHTIGQA6S9Qb-bTPRbLVZseSKZToaDGAAMBlMV3gXSRFUq9UwEkc6AqUGGMQA1OwAIwolHhaB7FrseFKFTQczQGloy5mA5HZAnb7jOZse6UGS4-GE4m0KDQswAXxhzIUrKRAB5oGiTO0OljupKCUSSTBWBSGUy4arEezObT5bzDsdgtFhfxRQ8JVUpcbZRAHUrHfyTmcePxLgqlkr8OYOc0ItB3k1ok1+Phrkj8uNJqVWKL+EISKJJAZmMZTBnKI4UOhnGJXD1aBJQqxzAA9ADEAH5fmAwr4ADquKG9-tDkc3PuD4d6AAk5kwSyIldxc2G+UBtFk4CUbAg1eQtbA9cbzb4MjYmkLInEoOQ1+LoIkD9vMm0L5LRh1QedTEpf+8aBKQkIDoFKSltAjaFl31JEDggHYkVbTse0nMdh1wD4FT0Udp2eTDsNw8cCLnBd-n4WhgDYVd+HlPlf1lRD2i7b9eSEWQXAgWgAEkVDYeDEJuKlnhkKkADY9CkXVnzkTieL4gSQHQG4PhEzkJKksxCHfWTkC43j0H4xilJuABmNTxL0dpA0INQdhAKMl0rd4vhTPN3gAQWQe9oBuDQdAUCUtF0IFtgC5AoS-CtYMTKk3hKLzkBuFFXg5D4AFZ0suSsJDi1hPO8oTUugDKspg7EwLyxMEsK1TbVKpc9QqzQwD4BgUGGABZMhHH+Fq+H4qkZFyt8qXlStNHEdqmFYbraz68RBuGobKugprukaPN+um0DJrEaaDDSxrK2oEAEnAdBaG4YY2FLctlUvVqds2Vg9oOxMnQFLUeRWdhkDyrZtpmfZPpONhcvpbQxttR62pmek3uBn7YQhl7oCBxgQeDEr-jpSk2Ch+l-sO9gMY6sJ0ampH2nor6ABZcdAwb6VyknYZ2inEcxiNjpi07zuSWobru1jfvZ+G0a5lAsedFFkfYRpNRRf50vRXVabBsmmE5qnMZhrXdt16WeRsjXSae+Gdf24GYY+RnOYtxgEaN5B5UjfByu6XxxBoa7WH5nZkm4W6mTEuXPaRb2xBoIX-ZoAXLtqEPrC5bKYqjmhNugRoU9pRqxYzkBrqVtWfy+m5C+uylTLDmRC9qOufZAepngjIgzYrpvuEb6OQAb6BC5bxyPcrIV4DXPNHDs8KHmnkKnjn-Qoojmp11tGvw-WpFY8oW1U5XrOYg5feiDF00tm1DEzYAAw7WdcE8EV6j0BV78f91n9fh-x4-l-r7ble3B1C0A+EmPMshF6hQAI6QJkKoMKIURYYkrEpAAWgoLwrANRamgCxJElI4pCHQDyHK6AADyFQyToHQQEZEnJcEMmoRg+khDGE0PgPLcG5DKGajihyCSH1sayCZlA+ksgDDWDEkyCQ3DaCcJkRQ2g0BeH1Rll9KB8jZHKJKuvNRJxhH41ERTcRloPjrxZrIiR0AxI8jNrIHmHst7lCqAARWGIrLUKsGE52pKBWoBghCNEpELCmPjahpwqriAACsMMx1hGgU1xC4iJ3QZo1GAaAqY0SvSVBcTIKu9COSmXGjFECrAgEgPeNRKoUScl5JqCUiquZ0mVKyTUup+SWG6MuDfO+38RSuy-u-AaEgX5vx-gNbQf9h7phisMm6ggEFLzLN+UeLZoBzV6gEdQ9Y2AFGsKVPQ-xPC1BvJINglkemgxGHwf4dBJC1hYFsOKLEABEKJXmgWaEIfIw8rDQAAKIADkAAi0BuKdSifUAFnVgWjA8qMbiZCgUtDaB7IAA

Comment: how can use css variables to solve the problem? I tried declaring my variable as so: --bkg-color: #ffffff an in my code if i do have a background color value then i document.body.style.setProperty('--bkg-color', pageDetails.backgroundColor) but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Iv'e added a edit with a working fiddle to show how to change css variables at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the demo - i realized i didn't have :root and needed to a # tag before my string value. Also would i still be able to use: `styleName: lighten(var(--class-color), 20%)`;

Comment: No you wont as lighten only exists at compile-time unfortunatly :( you can however use a javascript implementation of lighten/darken

Comment: Added a final edit with a javascipt implementation for scale-color in typescript

Comment: THANK YOU! Learned so much.